# Pyglet 3d control not working as intended

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, 3d, pyglet

I am currently learning the basics of pyglet and opengl. I have watched a number of tutorials and websites to learn pyglet and opengl, and I thought I would make a simple 3d game. However I am stuck on the camera movement controls and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the code. When I press `S` the camera moves back normally, but then when I press `W` it doesn't move, and if I press it again it moves but a little faster than before. Why is this happening?

```
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet.window import key
import math

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(3, ('v3f', [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0,      0.5, -0.5, 0.0,      0.0, 0.5, 0.0]),
                                                       ('c3B', [100, 200, 220,        200, 110, 100,       100, 250, 100]))

class Quad:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list_indexed(4, [0, 1, 2,    2, 3, 0],
                                                            ('v3f', [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0,      0.5, -0.5, 0.0,      0.5, 0.5, 0.0,      -0.5, 0.5, 0.0]),
                                                            ('c3f', [1.0, 0.0, 0.0,    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,   0.0, 0.0, 1.0,    1.0, 1.0, 0.0]))

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = [0, 0, 0]
        self.rotation = [0, 0]
        
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_z = 0
        self.speed = 1
    
    def controls(self, keys):
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_z = 0
    
        if keys == key.W:
            self.change_z = self.speed
        if keys == key.S:
            self.change_z = -self.speed
        if keys == key.A:
            self.change_x = -self.speed
        if keys == key.D:
            self.change_x = self.speed
        
        self.position[0] += self.change_x
        self.position[2] += self.change_z

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(300, 300)
        glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 1.0)
        gluPerspective(90, 0.5, 0.01, 1000)
        self.quad = Quad()
        
        self.player = Player()
    
    def on_key_press(self, KEY, MOD):
        self.player.controls(KEY)
    
    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        glTranslatef(*self.player.position)
        self.quad.vertices.draw(GL_TRIANGLES)
    
    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window(500, 500, 'My Window', resizable = True)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably misunderstood the `glTranslate` function.

`glTranslate` works in such a way, that it takes the current matrix and multiplies with a translation matrix given by parameters of `glTranslate`.

So, calling glTranslate(x, y, z) results in the following equation:

```
new_position = old_position + (x, y, z)
```

Which makes (x, y, z), if you call `glTranslate` every frame, the rate of change (i.e. the velocity).

### Why does it stop when I press S and the W?

Well, let's take a look at the code and the equation. You use `self.position` as parameter for `glTranslate`. So, your `self.position` is not the position but the current velocity (or rate of change) of the camera.

If you press `S` once, `on_key_press` will be called, with following effects:

```
self.change_z = -self.speed
self.position[2] += self.change_z # self.position[2] equals now -self.speed
```

Now press `W` once, yet again `on_key_press` will be called again, resulting in this:

```
self.change_z = +self.speed
self.position[2] += self.change_z # self.position[2] equals now 0, because self.position[2] was -self.speed; -self.speed + self.speed = 0
```

The implication is that every time you press either control key, you accelerate your camera discretely.

Assuming you pressed `S` twice after starting the program would cause `self.position[2]` to equal to `2 * -self.speed`.

### How to fix this?

Change the following

```
self.position[0] += self.change_x
self.position[2] += self.change_z
```

to

```
self.position[0] = self.change_x
self.position[2] = self.change_z
```

I really hope I made it clear, why `self.position` is actually a velocity and not the position. I suggest you rename `self.position` to `self.velocity` or something else along the lines.

---

Alternatively you can rebuild the matrix every time you change your position by doing the following:

```py
    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(90, 0.5, 0.01, 1000)
        glTranslatef(*self.player.position)
        self.quad.vertices.draw(GL_TRIANGLES)
```

---

I cannot help but give a further step. The fact that `self.position` is just a velocity (in your original version!), becomes apparent if you add a another method:

```
class Window(...):

    # ...

    def update(self, dt):
        self.clear()
        glTranslatef(*self.player.position)
        self.quad.vertices.draw(GL_TRIANGLES)
```

and extend `Window.__init__` with the following lines:

```
class Window(...):
    def __init__(...):
        # ...

        import pyglet.clock
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60)
        # pyglet now calls update(...) 60 times a second
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However now when I press the keys the screen turns purple or green.